# Discord.py AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'server'

Tags: python, attributes, discord.py, bots

Can you help me why I keep getting this error?
*AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'server'*

```
@commands.has_role("customer")
async def email(ctx,count=None,bomb_email=None,*,message=None):
    if message.server is not None:
        await ctx.send("nope")
    else:
        x = int(count)
    if message.server is not None:
        await ctx.send("yes")
        
    else:
        await ctx.send("nope")
```

Comment: Because your function has been called with message parameter being string so in your function, message (which is string) trying to access `server` attribute. Str doesn't have that attribute so it gives error.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get command's called server you can change `message.server` with `ctx.guild`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, you're trying to access a attribute called server which is not present the the `str` class. What I think you want is the [`discord.Message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=discord%20message#discord.Message) object. And even if you do that, there is no attribute called server for the `Message` class as well. I think what you need is the [`guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=discord%20message#discord.Message.guild) attribute which returns a [`discord.Guild`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=discord%20message#discord.Guild.banner) object or `None`.